# VSCode doesn't suggest built-in modules in TS files

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

When I start typing in my new Node project, for instance, "fs" in a `.js` file, I get the "fs" modules as a suggestion:

[image]

But when I try to type it in a `.ts` file, I get nothing:

[image]

Is there a way to get the suggestion also when I type a `.ts` file?

thanks!

I have tried to:

- Reinstall VSCode
- Reset its settings
- Reinstall the TypeScript extension
- Downgrade to a lower version of typescript
- Install ts-node

Comment: Do you have the TypeScript extension?

Comment: @MrDiamond Yes I have, even reinstalled it. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Just **install the [@types/node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node)** using npm or yarn to your project:

```
yarn add --dev @types/node
```